# What is the best practice for Android BroadcastReceiver and background Activity practice?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

If an Intent is launched with the intention of a specific Activity receiving it but the Activity is in the background, what is the suggested best practice in this scenario?

For example, an Activity may have triggered a long running login request to a remote server handled by an IntentService. During the long running login request the Activity is sent to the background. Since the BroadcastReceiver was registered in the Activity, it too is in the background.  The login process completes but the Intent to signal this is never picked up by the BroadcastReceiver.

Should I be using a ContentProvider to store the result from within the IntentService and register the Acitivty / UI for changes?  If I take this approach and the Activity is in the background will it receiver ContentProvider updates?

Answer (score 1):

Unless your application has just one activity, the authentication state (never logged in, logged in, login is expired) has to reside outside of any single activity. Whether that is in static data members or in some persistent store is up to you and is dependent upon business rules.

Your activity would simply interrogate that state in `onResume()` (e.g., examine the static data member).

Comment: Perhaps I can furnish my question with more detail. While a user logs in a progress dialog is displayed during authentication.  The dialog is dismissed when the broadcast receiver handles the "login successful" Intent. I understand that you answer still stands in that the progress dialog could be dismissed by interrogating the state stored in persistent storage somewhere. But this seems a like a common problem.  Are you saying that **all** events to be received in the UI layer require some kind of persistent storage mechanism? If so, why use BroadcastRecievers at all in an application?

Comment: @Jack: "Are you saying that all events to be received in the UI layer require some kind of persistent storage mechanism?" -- if you are trying to communicate with anything other than the foreground activity, it's a really good idea. "If so, why use BroadcastRecievers at all in an application?" -- to let a foreground activity know about the event.

Comment: But all foreground activities have the potential to be in the background (by definition), therefore BroadcastRecievers are rarely a good choice for communicating anything other completely unimportant events originating from the app itself?

Comment: @Jack: You are welcome to your opinion. Storing the `IntentService` results (e.g., via a static data member) and also sending a broadcast (to let a foreground activity know that something happened, which it otherwise will not realize) is one solution, but it is not the only one. For example, if the `IntentService` in question is initiated by the activity, you could pass a `Messenger` (tied to a `Handler` in the activity) via an `Intent` extra with your `startService()` command, and send results that way. Or try a `ResultReceiver`.

Comment: @Jack: Bear in mind that your proposed `ContentProvider` solution also requires "some kind of persistent storage mechanism. This approach may work, though I am skeptical that it makes sense for a login scenario (I'd call it "swatting a fly with a Buick").

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken ResultReceiver suffers from the same problem as a BroadcastReceiver in that it too will be sent to the background with an Activity.

Comment: I also don't think you can store anything in an IntentService, not even using static data members since the entire class could be unloaded.  So I am still left with a ContentProvider being the only solution?

Comment: @Jack: Classes do not usually get unloaded in Android. A `ContentProvider` is merely an API, nothing more. It says nothing about where the data is stored. Using a `ContentProvider` buys you absolutely nothing over the broadcast-plus-check-in-`onResume()` that I outlined, except that using a `ContentProvider` is probably somewhat more complex.

Comment: Ty for your input, but I'm really struggling with this: "usually not getting unloaded" is not the same as "always being around ".  Therefore I do not see static data-members as a solution.  I haven't read anywhere that suggests storing flags or any other data using static data-members in an IntentService.